# How to deal with reporting slowly changing dimensions

Tags: etl, data-modeling, datamodel, star-schema

For a client I am creating a data warehouse in which we have some slowly changing dimensions (or facts if that is even a thing?). For example we want to report the annually recurring revenue (ARR) for subscriptions and we want to have both the currently active and the expired subscriptions in there. So that we can see the ARR over a timeline.

The data we retrieve looks like this:

| subscription_id | account_id | ARR | start_date | end_date |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 1 | 10 | 01-01-2022 | 31-03-2022 |
| 2 | 2 | 20 | 01-01-2022 | 31-12-2022 |
| 3 | 1 | 5 | 01-04-2022 | 31-11-2022 |

So in this case the same account (account_id 1) renewed a subscription at the 01-04-2022. In the report of 2022 we want to see the ARR for all months in 2022. I've looked into slowly changing dimensions, however something I can not really see in that concept is how to report both the currently active license and the history in a dashboard. If we for example want to visualize the ARR in all of 2022 per month in a dashboarding tool we want to see both subscriptions for account_id 1 over the course of the year, not just the currently active one. This seems to be very tricky to do in most dashboarding tools.

To overcome this I've done the following. I created a calendar table with an interval of 1 month and I cross join it with the table above to generate a fact table. The end result would look like:

| timestamp | account_id | ARR |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 01-01-2022 | 1 | 10 |
| 01-01-2022 | 2 | 20 |
| 01-02-2022 | 1 | 10 |
| ... | ... | ... |
| 01-11-2022 | 1 | 10 |
| 01-11-2022 | 2 | 20 |
| 01-11-2022 | 2 | 20 |

This makes it really easy for the user of the reporting tool to filter on a specific month and show the ARR between the dates and over multiple subscriptions. It does however generate a lot of extra data, but at the moment the storage space is not an issue. And it makes it more of a transactional style table, but the ARR is not really a transaction (i.e. it is not really a sold product on a specific date).

My question is: Are there better ways of generating a fact table where the source data contains a date range?

Comment: Hi - it’s not clear to me whether you are asking how to design a data model or how to query an existing data model. You mention SCDs but then give a dataset that is not recognisable as an SCD. It’s also not clear what your ARR is - in the first dataset you show it as a single amount and I would expect that to be the annual revenue for that subscription; however in your result you are replicating this amount for every month - isn’t going to duplicate the ARR? If you want to allocate it monthly across the year then shouldn’t it be divided by 12?

Comment: Hi - The question is about designing a data model. Maybe I understand the concept of SCD incorrectly, in my understanding a table that has a start and end date (in my case subscriptions that are active and subscriptions that were active between a date range) is a slowly changing dimension. That is the first table I showed. We also have an MRR in the table, however I am not interested in the way the ARR is aggregated, it's just one of the facts I want to show. What I want to know is: Is there a better way of representing the facts than cross joining it to a table with a monthly interval.

Comment: @NickW I've changed the problem description a bit, I hope that the statement is a bit more clear to you now.

Comment: Hi - if you want to go down the route of designing a proper reporting (dimensional) model, which would make sense if your reporting requirements were complex enough to justify it, then I would suggest that you read a book on the topic (e.g. https://www.amazon.co.uk/Data-Warehouse-Toolkit-Definitive-Dimensional/dp/1118530802). From your comments it’s seems like your understanding of facts and dimensions is not yet at a level that would allow you to successfully design your own dimensional model

Answer (score 0):

There’s some confusion in the question on what makes for a slowly changing dimension: your core fact is more at the subscription level (when a renewal counts as a new subscription).

Also not sure how ARR can be reported on monthly- but that’s probably not too important to your question.

With clever calculations and queries you could use that fact as-is (eg show me all subscriptions where start date < month and end date >=month) or you could pre-explode the data to show all current subscriptions for each month, as you have. Those are pretty much the main two options.